# How to get an Update Statement to change the values depending on entries from another Table

Tags: sql-server

I have an Inventory Management Database in SQL Server. I have four tables. Items, Sales, Orders and Locations.

```
/*Start of Table Creations*/
CREATE TABLE Items
(
    itemID INT,
    itemName VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    quantityOnHand INT CONSTRAINT quantityOnHandCheck CHECK (quantityOnHand >= 0),
    quantityOnOrder INT CONSTRAINT quantityOnOrderCheck CHECK (quantityOnOrder >= 0)

    CONSTRAINT ItemsPK
        PRIMARY KEY (itemID)
)

CREATE TABLE Sales
(
    invoiceID INT,
    itemID INT NOT NULL,
    quantity INT CONSTRAINT salesquantityCheck CHECK (quantity >= 1),
    location INT,
    InvoiceDate DATE

    CONSTRAINT SalesPK
        PRIMARY KEY (invoiceID)
)

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    orderID INT,
    itemID INT NOT NULL,
    quantity INT CONSTRAINT ordersquantityCheck CHECK (quantity >= 1),
    orderDate DATE,
    delivered VARCHAR(1) CONSTRAINT ordersdeliveredCheck CHECK (delivered = 'Y' OR delivered = 'N')

    CONSTRAINT OrdersPK
        PRIMARY KEY (orderID)
)

CREATE TABLE Locations
(
    locationID INT,
    name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(70),
    street VARCHAR(70),
    city VARCHAR(70),
    province VARCHAR(2),
    country VARCHAR(25) CONSTRAINT countryDefault DEFAULT 'Canada',
    zip VARCHAR(7)

    CONSTRAINT LocationsPK
        PRIMARY KEY (locationID)
)
/*End of Table Creations*/
```

I have a few inserts which inserts sample data into these tables.

```
/*Insert current Inventory - Start*/
INSERT INTO Items
    (itemID, itemName, quantityOnHand, quantityOnOrder)
VALUES
    (1, 'Mocha Java', 3, 0),
    (2, 'Stevia', 5, 0)
/*Insert current Inventory - End*/

/*Insert current Invoices - Start*/
INSERT INTO Sales
    (invoiceID, itemID, quantity, location, InvoiceDate)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 1, GETDATE()),
    (2, 2, 1, 2, GETDATE())
/*Insert current Invoices - End*/

/*Insert current Orders - Start*/
INSERT INTO Orders
    (orderID, itemID, quantity, orderDate, delivered)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 6, GETDATE(), 'N'),
    (2, 2, 2, GETDATE(), 'N'),
    (3, 1, 6, GETDATE() + 1, 'N')
/*Insert current Orders - End*/

/*Insert current Locations - Start*/
INSERT INTO Locations
    (locationID, name, address, street, city, province, country, zip)
VALUES
    (1, 'CVO', 2106, 'Gordon Street', 'Guelph', 'ON', 'Canada', 'N1L 1G6'),
    (2, 'St John Ambulance (Kitchener Waterloo Branch)', 250, 'Gage Ave', 'Kitchener', 'ON', 'Canada', 'N2M 2C8')
/*Insert current Locations - End*/
```

Then I have a Bunch of Update statements

```
/*Update Inventory after a Sale was made - Start*/
UPDATE Items
    SET Items.quantityOnHand = Items.quantityOnHand - Sales.quantity
    FROM Items
    INNER JOIN Sales
    ON Sales.itemID = Items.itemID
/*Update Inventory after a Sale was made - Start*/

/*Update Inventory after an Order was made - Start*/
UPDATE Items
    SET Items.quantityOnOrder = Items.quantityOnOrder + Orders.quantity
    FROM Items
    INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Items.itemID = Orders.itemID
/*Update Inventory after an Order was made - End*/

/*Update Inventory after an Order was delivered - Start*/
UPDATE Items
    SET Items.quantityOnHand = Items.quantityOnHand +  Orders.quantity,
    Items.quantityOnOrder = Items.quantityOnOrder - Orders.quantity
    FROM Items
    INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Orders.itemID = Items.itemID
    WHERE Orders.delivered = 'Y'
/*Update Inventory after an Order was delivered - End*/
```

And Finally I have Select Statements to reflect these manipulations.

```
SELECT * FROM Items

/*SELECT * FROM Items
    WHERE quantityOnHand < 2*/

SELECT Sales.invoiceID, Items.itemName AS 'Item Name', Sales.quantity, Locations.name AS 'Location', DATENAME(mm, Sales.InvoiceDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(dd, Sales.InvoiceDate) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy, Sales.InvoiceDate) AS 'Invoice Date'
    FROM Sales
    INNER JOIN Items
    ON Sales.itemID = Items.itemID
    INNER JOIN Locations
    ON Sales.location = Locations.locationID
    ORDER BY Items.itemID ASC

SELECT Orders.OrderID, Items.itemName AS 'Item Name', Orders.quantity, DATENAME(mm, Orders.OrderDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(dd, Orders.OrderDate) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy, Orders.OrderDate) AS 'Order Date', Orders.delivered
    FROM Orders
    INNER JOIN Items
    ON Orders.itemID = Items.itemID
    ORDER BY Items.itemID ASC

SELECT locationID, name AS 'Name', address, street, city, province, country, zip
    FROM Locations
```

In the Insert for the Orders Table, I have two orders for one Item and the same amount of quantity, but when the UPDATE statement is run, it only reflects one of them. I used an INNER JOIN on the UPDATE statement in hope it would match Orders.itemID to Items.itemID and insert the appropriate quantity into the appropriate spot. But unfortunatly, instead of it increasing by 12... It only Increases by 6.

In Summary, It starts with

```
INSERT INTO Items
    (itemID, itemName, quantityOnHand, quantityOnOrder)
VALUES
    (1, 'Mocha Java', 3, 0),
    (2, 'Stevia', 5, 0)
```

Removes the following

```
INSERT INTO Sales
    (invoiceID, itemID, quantity, location, InvoiceDate)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 1, GETDATE()),
    (2, 2, 1, 2, GETDATE())
```

And is supposed to update Items.quantityOnOrder with a SUM of all respective records in

```
INSERT INTO Orders
    (orderID, itemID, quantity, orderDate, delivered)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 6, GETDATE(), 'N'),
    (2, 2, 2, GETDATE(), 'N'),
    (3, 1, 6, GETDATE(), 'N')
```

By using

```
UPDATE Items
    SET Items.quantityOnOrder = Items.quantityOnOrder + Orders.quantity
    FROM Items
    INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Items.itemID = Orders.itemID
```

Item 1 should have a quantityOnOrder of 12, but it shows 6.

I hope I made it easy to understand as it's alot :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here.  The primary one I see is data modeling.  You appear to have the same information stored two different places, namely `Items.quantityOnOrder` and `Orders.quantity`.  It would probably be best, unless performance or other constraints prohibit doing so, to get the quantity-on-order value directly from `Orders`:

```
SELECT i.itemID, COALESCE(SUM(o.quantity), 0) AS quantityOnOrder
FROM   Items i
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON i.itemID = o.itemID
GROUP BY i.itemID
```

If you do feel you must store the quantity in the Items table, you probably need to update that quantity with the sum from the Orders table:

```
;WITH Quantities AS
(
    SELECT i.itemID, COALESCE(SUM(o.quantity), 0) AS quantity
    FROM   Items i
    LEFT JOIN Orders o ON i.itemID = o.itemID
    GROUP BY o.itemID
)
UPDATE Items
SET    Items.quantityOnOrder = q.quantity
FROM   Quantities q
WHERE  Items.itemID = q.itemID
```

Further optimizations are possible, but I hope this points you in the right direction.

**Edit:**

In response to author's comment regarding updating `Items.quantityOnHand` when the value of `Orders.delivered` changes, it seems necessary to explore the possible ways that `delivered` can be set.  Ultimately, a good solution depends considerably on the business rules and other constraints.

For example, if triggers are encouraged in your environment, you might try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeliveryTrigger ON Orders AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
UPDATE Items
SET    quantityOnHand = Items.quantityOnHand - upd.quantity
FROM   (SELECT i.itemID, SUM(i.quantity) AS quantity
        FROM   inserted i
        LEFT JOIN deleted d ON i.orderID = d.orderID
        WHERE  i.delivered = 'Y'
        AND    (d.delivered IS NULL OR d.delivered = 'N')
        GROUP BY i.itemID) upd
WHERE  Items.itemID = upd.itemID
```

It might be better, however, to handle this logic in a stored procedure such as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeliverOrder
    @orderID INT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Orders o
           WHERE  o.orderID = @orderID
           AND    o.delivered = 'N')
BEGIN
    UPDATE Orders
    SET    delivered = 'Y'
    WHERE  orderID = @orderID

    UPDATE Items
    SET    quantityOnHand = Items.quantityOnHand - o.quantity
    FROM   Orders o
    WHERE  Items.itemID = o.itemID
    AND    o.orderID = @orderID
END
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Of course, you will probably need to modify these statements depending exactly what you are trying to do, exactly what your business rules are, etc.

Comment: Alright, So I ended up being able to complete it using this select statement.

SELECT i.itemName AS 'Item Name', i.quantityOnHand, SUM(o.quantity) AS quantityOnOrder
 FROM Items i
 LEFT JOIN Orders o ON i.itemID = o.itemID
 WHERE o.delivered = 'N'
 GROUP BY i.itemName, i.quantityOnHand
 ORDER BY i.itemName ASC

But I find that it removes the record when the quantity on Order Becomes ZERO. Any way you can think around this?

Comment: The purpose of the `LEFT JOIN` is to keep records from the `Items` table even when there are no corresponding records in the `Orders` table.  The problem is, if you then use a `WHERE` clause that references `Orders` (which you do here), you still lose `Items` records.  Add the clause to `ON` instead so you get  `ON i.itemID = o.itemID AND o.delivered = 'N'` and get rid of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: OKAY GREAT!!! it all works except for one tiny little part. Thanks for all your help so far. When I change the delivered field of the Orders TAble, It subtracts the order from the "quantityOnORder" created in the SELECT Statement... But doesn't add that to the respective quantityOnHand field. Thats what I orginally used the UPDATE Statements for. Perhaps an IF would work?

Comment: `quantityOnHand` would seem to have similar data-modeling issues in that the data is most likely elsewhere, and this field is a summary.  Eliminating this problem directly may be less practical, and solutions would depend on your use case and other constraints.  I will edit my answer to show some possibilities.

Comment: Thank you so much, It works Great now and I have learned alot.
Thanks again

Comment: Since you appear to be new here: if your question has been answered, consider "accepting" the most helpful answer by clicking on the big checkmark next to the answer.